# How to interface 6 HC-SR04 ultrasonic sensors rasberry pi

Tags: gpio, pi-4, hardware, sensor, wiringpi

I am a beginner to Rasberry Pi and working on a parking warning system for a go-kart. The plan is to use 6 ultrasonic sensors (3 at the front of the kart and 3 at the back) to achieve distance warnings when obstacles get too close to each respective sensor and display it on the dashboard. I've tried wiring 2, but can someone please explain how I can wire 6 ultrasonic sensors (and please be descriptive so it is easy to follow) to a Rasberry Pi 4 using the following equipment:

- Rasberry Pi 4
- Female to Male Jumper Wires
- HC-SR04 Ultrasonic Distance Sensor(x6)
- 1kΩ Resistors
- 2kΩ Resistors
- Full sized breadboard (x2)

Comment: Wire 1.  Get it working.  Repeat 5 times. Job's a good un.

Comment: What's the problem? Are you hoping to learn how to connect a HC-SR04?

Comment: Thank you for the comments, I really appreciate it. I tried setting up two different breadboards (for the front and back of the kart) which are supplied by the 5V power pins respectively (2 and 4). However, when both are plugged in, the second sensor (connected to pin 4) heats up extremely when I boot up the pi. I'm not sure what's the problem, I wired the two sensors identically, but the only differences are that they use different VCC pins, GND pins, and Echo and Trig pins

Comment: Here's some pictures if they help:https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1Cw1IAwGDgNI_b2StyqLrxCsw8L5kJKp7

Comment: The sensor that is heating up is the second one, on the right if you look at the pictures. I'd also like to note that when I used the same ground (34) and VCC (4) pins that I used for the second sensor (the one that is heating up) for the first sensor instead of its original pins (2 and  6 respectively), the first sensor also heats up.